# Assigning Semantic MediaWiki Properties automatically

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, semantic-mediawiki

I am using Semantic MediaWiki to organize a list of books with ISBN, publication year, pages, etc. Now I would like to set properties automatically for all results of an ask query.

Just for an example, the assumption is that I would like to assign the new property `[[Has current::true]]` to all books that were published in 2019. I think there should be a possibility to use a combination of #ask and #set  queries but I am not quite sure how to combine these.

In addition it would be nice if the property could actually be written on the result pages. But that is not completely necessary.

To get the books from 2019, an example query might be:

```
{{#ask: [[Category:Book]]
 |?Has publication_year::2019
}}
```

How can I assign the property `[[Has current::true]]` to all of the results?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Initiating actions from your ask query is a bit tricky because you'd have to somehow trigger the action when the query executes. Also you are expecting a kind of "one shot" result so it would not make much sense that the action happens on every rending of the page on which your ask query is residing. So I'd propose a multistep solution:

1. use a template in your ask-query that will create the #set statements you'd like to get without executing them yet.
2. cut&paste the result to a suitable place

There are other possible solutions to this which involve programming e.g. with PHP, Scribunto, Java or the like but this would need a much more elaborate answer which i do not think is suitable for stackoverflow.